# Adding Class current_page_item

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress-Design and i want to creat a Custom Menu.

```
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Menu', array(
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
    'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
    'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($items); echo '</pre>'; 
foreach($items as $item){
    echo '<div class="menu_entry"><a href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a></div>';
}
```

The problem is, i need the "current-page"-Class, which is WordPress creating - in the Standard Menu.

Any Ideas how to add this class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do a compare on the current page / cat etc ID against the menu items  object_id which is the ID of the page / category etc its linked to.

Something like (untested);

```
global $post;
$thePostID = $post->ID;
foreach($items as $item){

    if($thePostID === $item->object_id) {
        echo '<div class="menu_entry"><a href="'.$item->url.'" class="current-menu-item">'.$item->title.'</a></div>';
    }else{
        echo '<div class="menu_entry"><a href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a></div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: For some reason this only worked for me with a regular double equals (==) instead of the tripple equals.

Comment: It will not work if you've picked Category menu item for example as object_id is cat_id then.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak seconded for custom links

Comment: Look at the solution from @EthanC it is a lot nicer :)

Answer (score 22):

Solution time:

WordPress's function that adds these classes is [`_wp_menu_item_classes_by_context()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_menu_item_classes_by_context/). This is called already when you use `wp_nav_menu` but not `wp_get_nav_menu_items`. Fortunately, the latter provides a filter so we can do it ourselves:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'prefix_nav_menu_classes', 10, 3 );

function prefix_nav_menu_classes($items, $menu, $args) {
    _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context($items);
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: This is very useful - I take the $items and amend the classes with a switch statement allowing me to add in some more CSS friendly tag names for my front end developers. A lot nice than fighting with walkers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is usefull

Comment: Note from docs: *This function’s access is marked private. This means it is not intended for use by plugin or theme developers, only in other core functions. It is listed here for completeness.*

Answer (score 3):

Using the function [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/). This works fine in all the pages, including the Blog page.

See an example:

```
if ( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'menu' ) ) {
   foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
      $current = ( $menu_item->object_id == get_queried_object_id() ) ? 'current' : '';
      echo '<li class="' . $current . '"><a href="' . $menu_item->url . '">' . $menu_item->title . '</a></li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: The get_queried_object_id works for me. Thank you