# WordPress: Any way to get current page when using wp_get_nav_menu_items()?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm building a specialized menu. Normally, I'd use the regular menu functions with a custom nav walker, but this particular menu system uses other elements. I still want the authors to be able the edit the actual menu though, so I want to base it off of regular WordPress menus.

```
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
if (isset( $locations[ $menu_name ])){
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($locations[ $menu_name ]);
    if (count($menu_items > 0)){
        foreach ( $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $select_state = ''; // figure out if this is selected
            $oStr .= '<div class="flyout-menu ' . $select_state . '">';
            $oStr .= "\n";
            $oStr .= '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
            $oStr .= '<!-- ID:'.$menu_item->ID . ' object_id:'.$menu_item->object_id . ' thePostID:'.$thePostID . " -->\n";
            $oStr .= '</div>';
            $oStr .= "\n";
        }
    } else {
        $oStr .= '<!-- empty menu -->';
    }    
} else {
    $oStr .= '"' . $menu_name . '" not found.';
}
```

I'd like to add the regular current_page_item class to my menu element, but I don't see anything in the array returned by wp_get_nav_menu_items() that indicates this.

I found a few attempts online, but they all had invalid assumptions like the current page ID matching the menu object ID. (That's only true if the menu points to a Page.)

If there's no way to do this with wp_get_nav_menu_items(), I'll render the menu normally and capture it. Then parse it out and build my new menu-ish thing. But it would be simpler if I could just get the array from wp_get_nav_menu_items().

So is there a way to get which menu item should have current_page_item class without using wp_nav_menu()?

Comment: Can I ask what the new menu-ish things are that you need to add?  There are ways to append or prepend menu items in a super easy fashion.  If you provide those details, I might be able to get you a super simple solution!

Comment: In this case, I only want the top-level menu. I then match those up with custom post type "flyouts." I just wanted to building it with wp_get_nav_menu_items() instead of using wp_nav_menu() with a custom walker. (Which is my normal method for this sort of thing.)

Comment: So just to clarify... you allow a client to create a menu of whatever they want... you create a custom menu by grabbing only the top level items from the menu the client created, which could links to a page/post/category/whatever... then you create a custom sub menu for each top level item... and now you want the top level item, and custom sub menu items to obtain the current_page_item class.  Is this correct?  And are you doing this as an experiment?  I don't understand how this is easier than a custom menu walker...

Comment: If there were a way to know which item should have the current_page_item using  then this answer would be much simpler. This is one of those annoyng flyout menus. There is only one level to the actual menu. I have custom post types for the panels. If the menu item matches the name of the panel, I hook those together. Otherwise it leaves the item alone and it links normally. But at this point, yes it's looking like a custom walker.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019493/adding-class-current-page-item